# How to send large documents to ES for indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch

Our application submits text files for indexing to an Elasticsearch server, and the file's content is stored in a single field. And when we do that for large  files (250 MB) on a machine with limited resources, our application runs out of memory when loading file's content.

What is the recommended approach for sending large documents to ES? Is there a way to index them in chunks?

Thanks.

Comment: Please give more information. Which version of elasticsearch are you using? Did the problem goes away with newer versions, etc...